# Vuejs - re-focus an input-field after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I have built a form with Vuejs, which allows me to add word-pairs-objects to a array of words. After adding the focus should jump back to the first input field.

I have two forms on my page, the first one takes some general list information and will be hidden after submit. After this, the second form will be shown.

I tried `this.$$.input_lang1.focus()`, but the result was an error message (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'input_lang1' of undefined`).

I also have tried it with jQuery. This results in a correct focus, but the value of the second input field will not be removed.

Here is the [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76fua8js/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Give the input an id, then use pure javascript.

For example, if the input id is `initialInput`:

```
document.getElementById("initialInput").focus();
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/76fua8js/2/

Comment: @brotzka Did you try this?